# magento order API determine if product belongs to a bundle

Tags: magento-1.7, api, bundled-product

I am extracting new orders in Magento using API. I would like to know how I can tell if this is a simple product, bundle or component of a bundle.

To get details I use soapObject method for `sales_order.info`

```
$details = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $orderId);
```

when I dump details, it looks like this:

```
array(15) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(3) "232"
  ["weight"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(12) "BD22"
  ["name"]=>
  string(28) "BUNDLED_PRODUCT22"
  ["qty_ordered"]=>
  string(6) "2.0000"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_percent"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_percent"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["row_weight"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["price_incl_tax"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$details = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $orderId);
$productInfo = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'catalog_product', $details['it_product_id'] );
```

You are interested in `catalogProductReturnEntity=>type`. Read more here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

Comment: Brilliant. Will give it a try!