# magento 1.7 - API - determine if detail is simple, bundle, or component of bundle (Part II)

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, api, sales

follow up to 
[magento order API determine if product belongs to a bundle](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14438/magento-order-api-determine-if-product-belongs-to-a-bundle)

I am extracting new orders in Magento using API. I would like to know how I can tell if this is a simple product, bundle or component of a bundle.

To get details I use soapObject method for 'sales_order.info'

```
$details = $this->soapObject->call($this->sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $orderId);
```

Previous answer suggested that I use soapObject method for 'catalog_product' to determine if simple product or bundle... This is good start!

**However how can I tell if I am looking at a simple product as a detail or a simple product as a component of a bundled product.  Without a hint such as line number or sequence number I am not sure how to make distinction....**

when I dump details, it looks like this:

```
array(15) {
  ["product_id"]=>
  string(3) "232"
  ["weight"]=>
  string(6) "1.0000"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(12) "BD22"
  ["name"]=>
  string(28) "BUNDLED_PRODUCT22"
  ["qty_ordered"]=>
  string(6) "2.0000"
  ["price"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_percent"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["base_discount_invoiced"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_percent"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["tax_amount"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["row_weight"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
  ["price_incl_tax"]=>
  string(6) "0.0000"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the product type if you do another SOAP API call to `catalog_product.info`:

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.info', '4');
```

with '4' meaning product ID or SKU.

Please see the documentation for more details:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html